# SEO for angular js websiter

Tags: angularjs

How to do search engine optimization (SEO) for the  website built with angular js.

please explain how can we do it.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: @muller We are trying in the prerender.io, Thank you for your post

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is only one way to do this:

- By making html snapshots to serve up rendered JavaScript pages

Now there are different ways to achieve this.

**The easy way**

The most easiest way to do this would be to pay to a third party. I am familiar with [Prerender.io](http://prerender.io). I haven't used it myself, but when I needed SEO for a site built with AngularJS this was one of the options I have considered. Just browse the internet a bit and read up on their service, you will find some pretty good reviews.

**The alternative**

The alternative is [Angular-SEO by steeve](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo). Basically it does the same as prerender.io but it required you to launch the PhantomJS server on your own server (to which you need sudo access/rights). This, together with a bit of server configuration / tweaking in the htaccess file in my case did it for me. You basically detect the useragent / robot / scraper that is accessing your site and you redirect them to the location of your Angular-SEO server (address:port), which then returns a snapshot of the required page.

---

I decided to take the Angular-SEO= route, since it was an application for a client and I did not want to pay for the prerender service myself nor asking them to pay an extra monthly fee for a problem that I caused (I chose to use AngularJS without having investigated the SEO part (regret that))

The other day I saw that [DivShot](https://divshot.com/) has partnered with Prerender.io which makes it an interesting choice to consider for hosting